# Predicting at which point two objects collide

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, collision

I need this for a programming project:
B is moving on a circular path at constant speed.
Radius, period and theta are given and my program calculates the position at every update.
A is moving on a straight path at constant speed.
Initial position and speed are given.

[image]

Based on the given data I would like to be able to calculate the interception point and the time at which the objects collide. I try to research it but I couldn't figure it out the right formula.

I managed to obtain it with a work-around:
every update the program calculates the position of B, than the vector velocity and the new position of A... but it's too slow for great distances and small speeds.

Comment: Do you know for certain that they do in fact collide?

Comment: @Puk Good comment. Maybe the task should be to determine, based on the direction of A and a given speed of B,  the speed required by A for its position to coincide with B's on B's path.

Comment: Yes becouse I'm writing the programm so I can set the speed. I need the formula to correlate the two motions.

Comment: But how do you guarantee, given the initial conditions, that they are going to collide?

Comment: Do you know how to write equations for the two trajectories?

Comment: Actually, I believe you do not need any software to solve this problem, it has analytical solution, if it has one, just solve a quadratic

Comment: @G.Smith this is what I'm searching for. I've no problem translating in coding language but I can't figure them out.

Comment: What I mean is that it does not make sense to solve the problem as you are doing it, you can just solve it with pen and paper

Comment: @Wolphramjonny I can't figure the solution out. This is why I'm posting here. Can you help me writing this quadratic?

Comment: sure, but tomorrow

Comment: Very kind of you thank you!

Comment: One common tools that is used in programming: the intersection you describe is exactly the same intersection that occurs if you have a point object B' and a circle A' whose radius is the radius of A + radius of B.  It's often easier to work with a moving point source.  Also it can be easier to operate in one of their frames of reference: instead of having a moving A and B, pick one of them, fix it at (0,0), and have the other move in a more complex path that is the difference of the two motions.  Then you just have to solve for a time where that moving particle is near enough to (0, 0)

Comment: It's easy to figure out when A will cross the circle being "drawn" by B.  Then you simply figure out whether B will be there or not.

Comment: I don't see where there is any physics in this question at all.  It's a math problem devoid of physics and it doesn't have an unique answer as you've posed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x_A=x_{A0}+v_{xA}t$

$y_A=y_{A0}+v_{yA}t$

The following depend on what initial info you have, the ones I am writing are counter clock wise:

$x_B=R\cos(\omega t+\phi) $

$y_B=R\sin(\omega t+\phi) $

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to write the positions of A and B as a fuction of time. At collision you have the position of A equals the position of B. So set A=B and see if you can solve that for the time.